# RenderControl error

Tags: c#, asp.net

HI,
I have a grid with which I'm templating columns with and one column is a user control. Since I'm adding these in the code behind ( using ITemplate), I get an error when I try to render the UserControl. This particular user control does require a scriptmanager since it includes a ajax control (radcombobox).
The error I get is :
Script control 'LookupComboBox' is not a registered script control. Script controls must be registered using RegisterScriptControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().

I'm not sure even if my approach is correct using user control and using RenderControl.

Answer (score 0):

You must add script controls to a live controls collection in order to render them. Simply calling RenderControl won't do.

Comment: if the solution is to add to a live controls collection .how can this be accomplished?can you please help with a sample ?

Comment: Page.FindControl("placeholder").Controls.Add(myControl);